# Pdfcomment stopped working; icons still appear in pdf, text not showing up

Tags: pdftex, pdf, pdfcomment

**UPDATE:** *This seems to have to do with the pdfreaders on my mac/mac settings.  When I read the same files on readers on my Windows pc, the content does show up*

I use the 'pdfcomment' package in latex to produce a pdf document with annotations. All of a sudden it stopped working: icons still appear in the pdf, but the text of the comment is not showing up.

- Compiled with: Latex, LaTeX2e, pdfTeX (TexLive); also with XeLatex
- Tried in texshop, as well as  texstudio
- Viewed pdf in mac's Preview as well as in Skim

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,american,english]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\makeatletter
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This will  presumably lead to the maximum number of marriages given the information structure, and, in our model, the highest material welfare. However, people will also sometimes learn they were rejected, and feel a sting. \pdfcomment[icon=note]{testing a pdf comment} Introducing the CAE would give people a way to  avoid this sting, by rejecting and remaining ignorant (perhaps particularly when they anticipate likely being rejected).

\end{document}
```

Log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./testpdf.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 22 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latin9.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfcomment/pdfcomment.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datetime2/datetime2.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tracklang/tracklang.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tracklang/tracklang.tex))

Package datetime2 Warning: Date-Time Language Module `english' not installed on
 input line 1882.


Package datetime2 Warning: Date-Time Language Module `american' not installed o
n input line 1882.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-savepos.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/refcount.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marginnote/marginnote.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/soulpos/soulpos.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.s
ty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.st
y)) (/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)
)) (./testpdf.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/soulutf8.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/soul/soul.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.st
y)) (./testpdf.out) (./testpdf.out)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-pdfdoc.def)
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./testpdf.aux * soulpos - computing points - it may take a few seconds *
(./testpdf.upa)) ){/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/l
m-rm.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.p
fb>
Output written on testpdf.pdf (1 page, 29878 bytes).
SyncTeX written on testpdf.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on testpdf.log.
```

Comment: In my case, with TeX Live 2018 on Linux Mint and Evince, compiled with `pdflatex` I  don't see any icon, only a hidden link such that when clicked shows the text comment, or when mouse over, shows a tip text.

Comment: For me I do see the icons but the text doesn't come out. (Blank when clicked). But this *used to work* :(.

Comment: Works without problems here with a full up-to-date TeXLive. You get warnings about missing english and american modules for `datetime2`. So I guess your installation is at least incomplete. Install the english module of `datetime2` -> https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english or better all of `datetime2`

Comment: That's not the log-file but the terminal output. Show the real log-file.

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem seeing the comment if I move your language requirements to babel

```
    %\documentclass[11pt,american,english]{article}

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,USenglish]{babel}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\makeatletter
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This will  presumably lead to the maximum number of marriages given the information structure, and, in our model, the highest material welfare. However, people will also sometimes learn they were rejected, and feel a sting. \pdfcomment[icon=note]{testing a pdf comment} Introducing the CAE would give people a way to  avoid this sting, by rejecting and remaining ignorant (perhaps particularly when they anticipate likely being rejected).

\end{document}
```

However I recommend you consider where your comments are placed as this is my result

[image]

Comment: Thanks but switching to babel didn't change my outcome. Placement: I usually do put it in the margin, but I was trying to give a minimal working example. 

Just to confirm, on your pdf, when you click on it, you *do* see the comment text, correct?

Comment: see updated image included since I had omitted to use your font size but more important to your error the viewer I use does see the comment as shown, If you are still getting same or similar error messages after moving languages to babel we would need an addition [edit] to your question